# SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP -> 21 Days from now

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a table with some fields and a timestamp field named `timestart`.

What I would like to do is select all the records from my table where the field `timestart` is **21 days from now**.

But how can I do this?

Comment: you want to have 21 days `added` or `substracted`

Comment: I would like to have 21 days added!

Comment: ok i got it wrong .. i consider you want 21 days before... editing just check it

Answer (score 1):

you can have this with. if you want exact equals to timestamp. use `=`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

you can achive the same by using

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: This is between now and 21 days, I would like to have only timestamps == 21 days (from this day -> 16 february)

Comment: @nielsv may be this will help you achive.

Answer (score 0):

The [`datediff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function seems to meet the bill:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  DATE_DIFF (timestart, CURRENT_DATE()) >= 21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 21 DAY)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 20
```